# Updating cmake on gitlab runner for macos

Tags: c++, cmake, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using a shell gitlab runner on my macbook. It's task is currently to run a very simple yaml file to build my project using cmake.

```yaml
build:
    before_script:
        - git submodule update --init --recursive
        - mkdir cmake-build-debug
        - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" .
    script:
        - cmake --build . --target all -- -j 4
```

It returns this though: `CMake 3.17 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.16.3`.

When I add `- which cmake` to my before_script, it returns `/usr/bin/cmake`

When I run `ls /usr/bin | grep cmake` in my terminal, it doesn't return anything. When I run `brew info cmake` it returns the version as `cmake: stable 3.19.3`

How do I update cmake in my runner? Apparently It can't find brew in the before_script either.

PS: added bonus, if I set the minimum cmake version required to 3.16 it suddenly seems to be unable to link libm

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a tag. So it wasn't running on my computer but on a different server.